# Selecting item in typeahead returns blank value

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, typeahead

I am trying to get typeahead into an existing project so Im assuming the problem is

I have the following

```
  <pre>Model: {{entry.value | json}}</pre>
<input ng-show="entry.isToShow" class="form-control col-xs-12 " ng-model="entry.value" type="text" ng-required="entry.isRequired" uib-typeahead="name as dropitem.name for dropitem in entry.dropdownOptions | filter:$viewValue">
```

it shows the typeahead as Id expect but when I click on one or tab whilst one is highlighted, entry.value is not being populated as id expect and its staying blank - if I type something long enough that its not in the typeahead mode anymore and tab out it gets set  (eg selecting Sam from the last it shows nothing, if I type "sanfsjdngjdskgs" and tab to another control it show "sanfsjdngjdskgs"

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change your input tag to below

```
 <input ng-show="entry.isToShow" class="form-control col-xs-12 " ng-model="entry.value" type="text" ng-required="entry.isRequired" uib-typeahead="dropitem as dropitem.name for dropitem in entry.dropdownOptions | filter:$viewValue">
```

**Note: i just changed name to dropitem in uib-typeahead attributes**

Comment: Thank you very much - was driving me nuts, cant believe it was such a small oversight